# SQL Server, Consultar dato de una tabla mediante joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas, necesito ayuda ya que no puedo dar con un problema,
Tengo una tabla 'A' de Reuniones y una tabla 'B' de Usuarios, la tabla A contiene un campo llamado 'Organizador', que almacena el *Login* de un usuario (ej: Juan Perez, su login es 'jperez').
la tabla B almacena los usuarios y informacion de cada uno (Nombre completo, Email, Area, ID de Jefe)
al armar mi consulta, puedo obtener el nombre completo del usuario **Organizador** realizando un Join hacia la tabla Usuarios y agregando el campo directamente:

```
Select A.[ID],A.[Asunto],A.[IDObjetivo],A.[Ubicacion],A.[Organizador],A.[FechaCreacion],A.[FechaReunion],u.[fullname] AS Ejecutivo from [AgendaReuniones] A  
JOIN users u ON
  A.[Organizador] = u.[username]
```

mi gran duda es la siguiente, como puedo obtener al **Jefe del Organizador**?, en la tabla Users existe un campo llamado 'IDJefe' como se muestra a continuación:

```
ID     UserLogin        IDJefe
1001   Jefe1            NULL
1002   Jefe2            NULL
1003   Usuario1         1001
1004   Usuario2         1001
1004   Usuario3         1002
```

**Tabla Reuniones(En Rojo el campo Relacionado a 'Users')**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla Users(En Rojo el campo Relacionado a 'Reuniones')**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías poner tus 3 tablas ?

Comment: Tendrías que usar otro join entre la tabla user y la de jefes, y en la consulta en vez de poner el IdJefe pones el nombre del jefe

Comment: para los dos, la tabla jefes no existe, como mencione en el post, son solo 2 tablas, una de Reuniones y otra de Usuarios, el Jefe se diferencia por el campo 'IDJefe', cuando es NULL es Jefe, cuando contiene un ID es un usuario Ejecutivo(y el ID que contiene hace referencia a la misma tabla, como indiqué en el post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el join con la segunda tabla de nuevo con un alias como si fuera una tercera así:

```
Select A.[ID],A.[Asunto],A.[IDObjetivo],A.[Ubicacion],A.[Organizador],A.[FechaCreacion],A.[FechaReunion],u.[fullname] AS Ejecutivo, b.[fullname] AS Jefe
from (([AgendaReuniones] A  
LEFT JOIN users u ON A.[Organizador] = u.[username]) 
LEFT JOIN users b on u.IDJefe = b.ID)
```

Comment: Recuerdo intentar hacer esto sin dar resultados, quizas realice mal los joins o indiqué mal los criterios, esto era lo que estaba buscando, muchisimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

son solamente 2 tablas, me imagino que no debiera ser muy complejo,
existe algún Primary key que se hederé de la tb1 a la tb2 o viceversa?
con un INNER JOIN podrías hacerlo en ese caso.
y si deseas traer a los jefes que son NULL, me imagino que podrias condicionar el campo con un IS NULL.

Comment: amm creo que desde la tabla 2 (USERS) hereda a la tabla 1 (REUNIONES), mi problema es que la informacion de la tabla REUNIONES  es algo incompleta para una presentacion de datos, lo que necesito en este caso, es adicionar a una consulta de esta tabla de reuniones, el nombre del organizador y el jefe del organizador, el organizador y el jefe son usuarios, de la tabla USERS (ver tabla en el post), y la unica relacion entre estas tablas es el campo Organizador(que almacena el nombre del User), actualizare el post para dar mas info

Comment: si puedes subir una foto de cada una de las tablas con sus campos,
y otra imagen de las tablas pobladas, asi entender un poco mas.

pero por lo que entiendo:

`select u.username from usuario  as u
inner join reunion as r on r.organizador=u.username
where u.idjefe IS NULL`

Comment: Las fotos estan en el post